# Change vendor directory path for Symfony project

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, vendor

I'm working to create two symfony projects with one vendor directory

```
// I need to change this :
my-project1/
└─ vendor/
 my-project2/ 
└─ vendor/ 

// To this :
vendor/
my-project1/
my-project2/
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would advise you not to do it (why do you want it anyway?), but answering the question: you have to set up [vendor-dir](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#vendor-dir) in both projects to `../vendor`.